# Ошибка в структуированных данных

Tags: schema.org

Выходит ошибка в такой schema

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "Organization",
"name": "Создание сайтов в Алматы от Modern Design Lab",
"url": "https://mdlab.kz/",
"logo": "https://mdlab.kz/img/logo.png",
"contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+7-777-433-38-22",
    "contactType": "sales",
  }],
"sameAs" : [{
"https://vk.com/public151532814",
"https://www.facebook.com/MD-Lab-351217825313347/",
"https://twitter.com/MdLabWebSite",
"https://www.instagram.com/mdlabkz/"
}]    
}
</script>
```

Перед SameAs ошибка
**Отсутствует символ "}" или название объекта.** Что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Будет работать вот так:

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Создание сайтов в Алматы от Modern Design Lab",
    "url": "https://mdlab.kz/",
    "logo": "https://mdlab.kz/img/logo.png",
    "contactPoint": [{
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "telephone": "+7-777-433-38-22",
        "contactType": "sales"
    }],
    "sameAs": [
        "https://vk.com/public151532814",
        "https://www.facebook.com/MD-Lab-351217825313347/",
        "https://twitter.com/MdLabWebSite",
        "https://www.instagram.com/mdlabkz/"
    ]
}
</script>
```

**Что изменилось?**

1. Убрал запятую после "contactType": "sales"
2. Убрал фигурные скобки из структуры "sameAS":

**Почему не работало?**

1. В объектах нельзя ставить запятую после последней пары свойство-значение.
2. Если вы описываете объект с помощью фигурных скобок, то он должен содержать не только значения, но и имена свойств (а в блоке "sameAs" объявлены только значения в виде URL-адресов).

**Где проверить разметку?**

В Яндекс.Вебмастере на странице https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/microtest/ – нужно нажать кнопку «или вставьте фрагмент HTML-кода», а затем вставить код в поле ввода и нажать "Проверить".